# Expand a table in EPPlus C#

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

Is there any way that I can expand an existing table in EPPlus in C#.  The way my program works is I create the table with only 2 rows and keep adding more.  I just can't seem to find any sort of resize method in `ExcelTable`.  Is there a dedicated method for this, or do I need to use some sort of alternative?

**Edit:**  Okay I'm just going to clarify this.  **I already have EPPlus working and making an ExcelTable.  My question is: How can I make an existing ExcelTable larger (add more rows)?**

Comment: EPPlus is for export to excel, what do you want actually?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, my answer below will read an Excel file into memory and add a row, then overwrite the file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is about one year old, but hoping that someone still needs an answer, there is a direct solution, although not complete because of a bug in EEPlus (I am working with v4.1).

ExcelWorksheet has an [InsertRow(Int32, Int32, Int32)](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/EPPlus/EPPlus/ExcelWorksheet/M/InsertRow) method. If you insert rows in an area that is part of the table, the table is also expanded. Simply use it's Address property to get the bounds. Just make sure to insert between the first and last row of the table.

There is a flaw I know about related to cell validation: even if you use the overload which can copy style from an existing row, the validation is not copied. Even worse, the validation is left where it was and it is not shifted with the cells. I have not tested, but I believe that if the validation has a range and not a cell as target, that one is also expanded if you insert rows into that range.

This won't help you if you wish to expand the table on data aready in the Worksheet - but you can still move rows.
And neither when you have many tables side-by-side (which is a nightmare).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
However, if a chart series was bound to a whole column it would ignore inserted rows. Despite with manual inserting chart was updated.
Maybe you know workaround for such case?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately, there is no direct method.  Not quite sure why but the developers of EPPlus choose to make the `ExcelTable.Address` property ready only.  So the most obvious choose would be to create a new table, copy all of the properties (assuming you know all of them that are needed) and delete the old one.  Not very ideal since you could miss something.

But I see two other others - next exactly pretty either but better then the copy/delete.  Assume a table like so:

[image]

**Option 1** you could fork the EPPlus source code and make the property needed read/write.  You would do this in the file `ExcelTable.cs` by changing:

```
    public ExcelAddressBase Address
    {
        get
        {
            return _address;
        }
        internal set  //REMOVE internal KEYWORD
        {
            _address = value;
            SetXmlNodeString("@ref",value.Address);
            WriteAutoFilter(ShowTotal);
        }
    }
```

by removing the `internal` keyword.  But of course you will have to be careful doing so does not break something else along the way.  With this, you can do something like:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Expand_Table.xlsx");

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    //Added 11th data row assuming the table is from A1 to C11 (Header row + 10 data rows)
    worksheet.Cells["A12"].Value = 10;
    worksheet.Cells["B12"].Value = 100;
    worksheet.Cells["C12"].Value = Path.GetRandomFileName();

    var tbl = worksheet.Tables["TestTable1"];
    var oldaddy = tbl.Address;
    var newaddy = new ExcelAddressBase(oldaddy.Start.Row, oldaddy.Start.Column, oldaddy.End.Row + 1, oldaddy.End.Column);

    tbl.Address = newaddy;

    pck.Save();
}
```

**Option 2** would be the safer option but most "dirty" by using a string replace on the XML.  We cant assume there is only one reference to the address because, for example, the AutoFilter could be turned on.  Here is what the default XML will look like when you create a table in excel (note the 2 references to the address):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<table xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main" id="3" name="TestTable1" displayName="TestTable1" ref="A1:C11" totalsRowShown="0">
    <autoFilter ref="A1:C11" />
    <tableColumns count="3">
        <tableColumn id="1" name="Col1" />
        <tableColumn id="2" name="Col2" />
        <tableColumn id="3" name="Col3" />
    </tableColumns>
    <tableStyleInfo name="TableStyleMedium2" showFirstColumn="0" showLastColumn="0" showRowStripes="1" showColumnStripes="0" />
</table>
```

So we can do a string replace like this:

```
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Expand_Table.xlsx");

using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    //Added 11th data row assuming the table is from A1 to C11 (Header row + 10 data rows)
    worksheet.Cells["A12"].Value = 10;
    worksheet.Cells["B12"].Value = 100;
    worksheet.Cells["C12"].Value = Path.GetRandomFileName();

    var tbl = worksheet.Tables["TestTable1"];
    var oldaddy = tbl.Address;
    var newaddy = new ExcelAddressBase(oldaddy.Start.Row, oldaddy.Start.Column, oldaddy.End.Row + 1, oldaddy.End.Column);

    //Edit the raw XML by searching for all references to the old address
    tbl.TableXml.InnerXml = tbl.TableXml.InnerXml.Replace(oldaddy.ToString(), newaddy.ToString());

    pck.Save();
}
```

Comment: I don't think all of this is necessary. The `Address` is read-only, because it changes based on the amount of data in the report. If you read the file into memory as an `ExcelPackage` and add data to it, the `Address` information will be changed accordingly.

Comment: @dubstylee Have you been able to do this with Epplus and an `ExcelTable` object?  The code you posted (and update) will added a value to the cell below the last empty cell in the `Worksheet` but it will NOT update the `ExcelTable`.

Comment: I have not. I am not sure if I understood the OP question correctly, but it doesn't seem like using an `ExcelTable` is necessary. I just access the data directly from the `Worksheet`, which in my head is logically the same as an `ExcelTable`...

Comment: @dubstylee  `Worksheet` and `ExcelTable` are two completely different object.  That is what he meant by "How can I make an existing ExcelTable larger (add more rows)" in his edit.

Comment: Ah I see. I will leave my answer in case it helps someone else who comes across this question. It depends on what the OP is trying to do, may not be necessary to use `ExcelTable` at all.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I think I like the first method the most.  I will try it when I get a chance.

Comment: @user2255090  Sure.  Remember to mark the answer as the correct one if it ends up working for you to close it out (you also get points :))

Comment: Yup I'll do that when I get it working here, don't worry!

Comment: I tried the second answer - replacing the old address range in the xml with the new address range and it worked perfectly - no errors when opening the document. Thank you!

Comment: @Jordan I suggest you change the selected answer to the other one, which is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Option 1 can be easily done via Reflection though.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I found an extremely fast way to dump an SQL DataTable on an Excel Table.

**18004 rows in just 04.2 seconds**

My template contained formulas that when extending the table were inherited to the new rows.

**Template.xlsx**

[image]

**Report_with_Epplus.xlsx**

[image]

```
public void xlsEpplus()
    {
        try
        {
            TimeSpan stop;
            TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            Database DB = new Database();
            DB.msConect();

            string sql = "SELECT * FROM table_test";
            DataTable dt_tab = DB.xSqlMs(sql);

            string Template = "D:\\Plantillas\\Template.xlsx";
            string filePath = "D:\\Plantillas\\Report_with_Epplus.xlsx";
            File.Copy(Template, filePath, true);


            ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage();

            pck.Load(new FileStream(Template, FileMode.OpenOrCreate));

            ExcelWorksheet ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

            var a = ws.Cells["A1"].Value;


            int i = 2;
            ws.InsertRow(i, dt_tab.Rows.Count);
            ws.Cells["A2"].LoadFromDataTable(dt_tab, true);

            pck.SaveAs(new FileInfo(filePath));

            stop = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
            Console.WriteLine("xlsEpplus_While:" + stop.Subtract(start));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```